# Build a Sum with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Target: Build a sum in a specific Column.

In this row there are Special Values:   "Start" and "EEnd"

I want to Sum the Values of Column A from "Start" to "EEnd"..

Example

```
A         B         
1         Start         
2                  
3                  
4                  
5         EEnd         
1         Start
5         
2         EEnd
```

First Sum sould be 15 and the next 8.

Till the last "EEnd"

Result should be in Column C next to the "EEnd".

My Try:

```
Sub Try()
 Dim rngTreffer As Range
 Dim lngC As String
 Dim strAdresse As String
 Dim alteAdresse As String

 With Worksheets("Tabelle2")

  Set sStart = .Columns(2).Find("Start", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
  Set sEnd = .Columns(2).Find("EEnd", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

  If Not sStart Is Nothing Then

     sStartAdress = sStart.Address
     sEndAdress = sEnd.Address

     Do

    Range("A1") = Application.Sum(Range("sStartAdress:sEndAdress"))

  'here i get an Error:Run-time error '1004' : Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed

        Set sStart = .Columns(2).FindNext(sStart)
        Set sEnd = .Columns(2).FindNext(sEnd)

     Loop While sStart.Address <> sStartAdress
  End If

 End With

End Sub
```

Comment: And where would these results go?

Comment: In Column C next to the "EEnd"

Comment: So where is your VBA code you are trying with? Or were you expecting to find someone coding it for you without any effort from your side?

Comment: Run-time error '1004' : Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed  
              at Cells(1, 3) = Application.Sum(Range("sStart.Address:sEnd.Address"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your range is `"sStartAdress:sEndAdress"`, that's the error. But you want a range `"A2:A6"`.

So you have to move out the variables of the "..". You get something like `Range(sStartAdress&":"&sEndAdress)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Try()
   Dim rngTreffer As Range
   Dim lngC As String
   Dim strAdresse As String
   Dim alteAdresse As String

   With Worksheets("Tabelle3")

      Set sStart = .Columns(2).Find("Start", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
      Set sEnd = .Columns(2).Find("EEnd", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

      If Not sStart Is Nothing Then

            sStartAdress = sStart.Address
            sEndAdress = sEnd.Address

         Do

            sStartRow = sStart.Row
            sEndRow = sEnd.Row

            Cells(sStartRow, 3) = Application.Sum(Range("A" & sStartRow & ":" & "A" & sEndRow))

            Set sStart = .Columns(2).FindNext(sStart)
            Set sEnd = .Columns(2).FindNext(sEnd)

         Loop While sStart.Address <> sStartAdress
      End If

End With

End Sub
```

This is the first solution.

One Problem.. it never stop Looping ... i think there is a error with : 
     Loop While sStart.Address <> sStartAdress

But it does the work. Ill figure it out.

@ IQV

War das Und. (ok sieht man ja :D) thx!

Comment: sStart.Address is always == sStartAdress, so <> is never true and the loop is infinite. But you could use your `alteAdresse` to remind the first result and use this as cancel criteria.